# How can I use WearableActivity with LiveData and ViewModel

Tags: android, wear-os, android-architecture-components

I want to be able to use the Lifecycle components from the new Android Architecture Components in my Wearable app (same as I do in my Android app).

In my main Android app I put [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html) fields in a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel.html). This [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel.html) can then be accessed/bound from both my Activity and my Fragments. To do this I use the method [ViewModelProviders.of](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.html#of(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity)) which expects either [android.support.v4.app.Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) or [android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html). So far so good...

The problem I'm facing is that my Wear app is based on the [WearableActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/activity/WearableActivity.html) class which extends from [android.app.Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) rather than from [android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html). This prevents me from using [ViewModelProviders.of](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.html#of(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity)) in my wearable app.

I've asked around and tried to find alternative solutions, but I don't know the internals of ViewModelProviders so I can't get around this problem right now. If there isn't an answer I hope someone who works on these components can have a look at this. It would be awesome to be able to use ViewModel & LiveData throughout my applications (mobile and wear).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:
[AmbientMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/ambient/AmbientMode.html) seems to be the new way to handle this.

As @codingjeremy mentioned in his post, they have now introduced this with Android Support Library 27.0.0.

---

Original:

I got around this by copying the implementation in WearableActivity verbatim to a new WearableFragmentActivity class defined in my own project and then changing it to extend FragmentActivity.  Getting this supported by Google directly would be the ideal solution, but this should work if you're looking for a workaround in the meantime.

Comment: Nice solution, was really easy to implement as well. Hopefully this will be supported by Google in the future, but for now this seems to work 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet possible as `ViewModel` depends on Support Fragments (i.e., `FragmentActivity`).

Please file a feature request for a `WearableFragmentActivity` equivalent at [issuetracker.google.com](http://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: I see there is already a related issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62185208

I've added a comment in that issue linking here.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work using `AmbientMode.AmbientCallbackProvider` instead of WearableActivity.

It is the new preferred method and it still gives you the `onEnterAmbient()`, `onAmbientUpdate()`, and `onExitAmbient()` but also lets you use `Activity` (or any sub classes... FragementActivity, etc.)... which allows you to support the Architecture components.

[Official docs call out the details and code](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this porting of architecture component: [LifeCycleData](https://github.com/baldapps/LifeCycleData)