# Android Architecture Component in Android Wear App

Tags: android, wear-os, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I want to use [architecture-components](https://developer.android.com/jetpack#architecture-components) in wear app. In wear app i can't use `ViewModel` in [WearableActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/activity/WearableActivity.html) as `WearableActivity` depends on `Activity` not `FragmentActivity`. I found an answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46203123/1292557) thread. This answer suggested use `FragmentActivity` with [AmbientModeSupport](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/ambient/AmbientMode.html)

There is also a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62185208) for this support, but that issue status is `Won't Fix (Infeasible)`.

So i want to know using `ViewModel` in Wear is good choice or not, as there is no official support?

If there is no problem with `ViewModel` in Wear app then which is the good way to use `ViewModel`?  `FragmentActivity` with [AmbientModeSupport](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/ambient/AmbientMode.html) ?

I want to hear from some experts. What they think about `ViewModel` use in Wear app.

Thanks in advance.